# login command not prompting for username/password

Tags: fedora, login

Under fedora-14 'login' command asks for username and password.

```
 $login
 login: 
 Password:
```

but with recent versions (Fedora19) 'login' command is not prompt for username/password, it Just hangs. How to get back its old functionality?

Comment: I get `login: Cannot possibly work without effective root`

Comment: Is that Fedora system? Are you able to run with sudo login ? thanks for the response.

Comment: No it's ubuntu. With `sudo login` it works as expected, showing a prompt to login.

Comment: okay thanks. I don't have any luck with Fedora "sudo login" display error message like 'Stopped                 Sudo login'. Will explore ubuntu login command  or may be copy it to fedora and see what happens!

Comment: This sounds like you're abusing `login` for things it wasn't meant to do. What is it you're really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to set tty.js to accept 'login' command (instead of bash) to prevent allowing everyone to login without password. https://github.com/chjj/tty.js

Answer (score 4):

`login` command is configured under `/etc/login.defs`, in particular you are interested in two variables:

```
#If defined, this file will be output before each login prompt.
ISSUE_FILE     /etc/issue

# Password prompt (%s will be replaced by user name).
LOGIN_STRING           "%s's Password: "
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a login prompt <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> where n is between 2 and 6

<kbd>F7</kbd> is your graphical login.  I do this all the time on my laptop.  No need to edit login.defs etc.